# Hint for calculating $\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\Gamma (\frac{3}{2})=1$

Tags: probability, gamma-function

I am calculating the variance of a standard normal distribution. I know there are other ways to do this, but I want to use the gamma distribution. I calculated up to $\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\Gamma (\frac{3}{2})$. But I don't understand why the following calculation results in 1. Please give me some hint for

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\Gamma (\frac{3}{2})=1$$

Comment: Use reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \pi/\sin(\pi z)$ and $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$.

Comment: By the definition of the gamma function, $z\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$. $z = 1/2$ here and $\Gamma(1/2)$ is known to be $\pi^{1/2}$; therefore $\Gamma(3/2) = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(1/2) = \frac{1}{2}\pi^{1/2}$. $\frac{2}{\pi^{1/2}}$ is nothing but the reciprocal of $\frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2}$, so of course their product is $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can brute force compute from the definition of $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x - 1} e^{-t} \ dt$
$$
\Gamma\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big) = \int_0^\infty t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t} \ dt = -\underbrace{ \Big[t^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-t}\Big]_0^\infty }_{= 0} + \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t} \ dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-s^2} \ ds = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$